# Multiple auth schemes in hapijs?

Tags: hapi.js

I am building an application using hapi.js . The clients of this application are  going to be either a web application, so authentication is via JWT in the coookie or via OAuth2 clients which are going to be sending the Bearer key header.

Is there some way that the framework allows using both schemes for the same route? I want the authentication to fail if both schemes fail, but pass if either of the go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at http://hapijs.com/api#route-options under `auth.strategies`. This will allow you to set multiple strategies for your route. You can define the behaviour with `auth.mode`.

Answer (score 1):

hapi supports [multiple authentication strategies for a route](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-allow-multiple-authentication-strategies-for-a-route). Register the indiviual plugins for authentication and set the default auth scheme afterwards.

```
var Hapi = require('hapi')  
var BasicAuth = require('hapi-auth-basic')  
var CookieAuth = require('hapi-auth-cookie')

// create new server instance
var server = new Hapi.Server()

// register plugins to server instance
server.register([ BasicAuth, CookieAuth ], function (err) {  
  if (err) {…}

  server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { validateFunc: basicValidationFn })  
  server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', { password: '…' })

  server.auth.default('simple')
})
```

Each authentication scheme may require dedicated configuration (like a cookie password, a validation function, etc.) that you need to provide.